# How to know when android accessibilty service gets disconnected?

Tags: android, accessibility

I have written a accessibility service. When it gets connected

```
public void onServiceConnected() {..}
```

gets called. But sometimes the service dies an there is no

```
public void onServiceDisconnected() {..}
```

method while extending AccessibilityService. How can I know when to prompt the user that the accessibility service has died and you need to turn it back again ?

Comment: I faced the same issue. There was a crash that happened under onAccessibilityEvent() which caused the accessibility service to disconnect without calling disconnected . Using try catch under onAccessibilityEvent might help.